# How to remove all keys from JSON?

Tags: java, json

I am using json-lib.

```
[{"VALUE":0},{"n1":1,"n2":2,"n3":3,"n4":4},{"item1":10,"item2":20,"item3":30},{"n5":5},{"item_40":40,"item_50":50}]
```

I want to convert this code so it looks like this:

```
[[0],[1,2,3,4],[10,20,30],[5],[40,50]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: The requested format is rather useless.

Answer (score 0):

In json, "{}" mark mean dictionary(key-value)type.

if you want to remove key, get value in {} and add it to list([])

[[0],[1,2,3,4],[10,20,30],[5],[40,50]]